# Considering USB 3.0 Cable and PCB Layout

Tags: pcb-design, usb, high-frequency

I'm trying to connect usb Vision3.0 camera to Board.

There are cables and other boards between the camera and the board.

I am attaching the picture material.

[image]

I checked a few things.

1. USB 3.0 has 9 wires.
   4 from USB 2.0 (VCC, GND, D+, D-)

   - 5 new for super (SSTX+/-, SSRX+/-, GND) and Shield
2. USB 3.0 Signal Frequency is 5Ghz.

A. How can I design the Shield signal to pass the 5Ghz signal?

B. usb 3.0 have to shield. I'm trying to pass the shield signal to the cable. Is this a good way?

Comment: Dumb question, why can't you connect a real certified shielded USB 3.0 cable from the camera to the end board? They seem to be located in the same case. The way you ask this question makes me think you're not prepared to successfully route 5 GHz signals over four PCBs and various cables.

Comment: usb 3.0 cable is thick. so Not suitable for my design. 
So I'm contemplating a method like this.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I design the Shield signal to pass the 5Ghz signal?

You're not going to be able to do this without some kind of signal integrity software (you'll probably need a 3D FEM which are 80k+) and you'll have to model every connector and cable. USB super speed runs at 2.5 GHz, but each connector and PCB needs to support that speed and my feeling is that's going to be very difficult to do with the number of connectors and pcbs you have especially if this is your first time.

This is what I would do if I was in your situation: consider putting a USB 3.0 PHY on the camera connector board, this would come at the cost of more data lines. But the data alliance would run to the lower speed and it would be easier to maintain signal integrity

Or run a shielded USB 3.0 cable from the camera to the other board.